# Large arrays &  javascript comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have two very large multidimesional arrays(4000+). I get the first array as a response from the server where, i have to create dom nodes for each of these array elements. Once this process is finished i have to send another request where i will get another list of elements which will be a subset of the first list, based on the second list i have to modify some elements in the first list (and reflect these changes in the DOM as well). This process takes a very long time to finish, is there any way to accomplish this without two for loops? Or perhaps a faster comparison?

**Scenario**

> The real world example would be as follows, consider a group of people
>   in  a particular area (arr1). In DOM this would be represented as
>   `CheckBox - Name` Now consider a group of people who have been administered with a
>   particular vaccine (arr2), Now arr2 has the list of elements for which
>   the checkbox should be checked. The whole list(arr1's dom representation) has to be shown at all
>   costs.

Arrays are of the type

```
[ ["index", "name", "age"],............. ["4000-index", "4000-name", "4000-age"]]
```

Here is a pseudo code..

```
//First request, get the response (resp) and Create DOM elements accordingly
for(var i=0, iLen=resp.length; i<iLen; i++)
{
  // Checkbox and <span id='entry-"+resp[i][0]+"'>resp[i][1]</span>
}
// At a later stage in the code...
//Request server for the second list get the response (resp)
arr2 = resp // Second Array

// Walk through the dom, get the list of span elements and store their ids in an array arr1 
for(var i=0, iLen=arr1.length; i<iLen; i++)
{
  for(var j=0, jLen= arr2.length; j<jLen; j++)
  {
    if(+arr2[j][0] === +arr1[i][0])
    {
      //checkbox attr = 'checked'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have some example code - and maybe an example dataprovider? would make it easier to help :-)

Comment: maybe you should rethink what the server sends to the client. since the 2 lists are related  , why 2 queries ?

Comment: @camus & santa : I have updated my question for ease of understanding. The two queries are because these lists are maintained in different databases. Hence.

Comment: you should definitely consider going a different road for this.

Comment: +1 , you should do the "mash up" server side.

Comment: @AshwinGanesh - you should consider sending in the second set of data as an object - {id:123, attrib1:'something', attrib2:'something else'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send in the second set of data that your receive as an object with the following structure, you could get some really good performance boost.

```
var subset = {
    anID:{
        bcg: true,
        someOtherProp: false,
        //and so on
    }
}
```

Then all you need to modify your DOM elements -

```
for (var id in subset){
    //do whatever needs to be done
}
```